# Binding a date string parameter in an MS Access PDO query

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

I've made a PDO database class which I use to run queries on an MS Access database.
When querying using a date condition, as is common in SQL, dates are passed as a string. Access usually expects the date to be surrounded in hashes however. E.g.

```
SELECT transactions.amount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.date = #2013-05-25#;
```

If I where to run this query using PDO I might do the following.

```
//instatiate pdo connection etc... resulting in a $db object
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT transactions.amount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.date = #:mydate#;'); //prepare the query
$stmt->bindValue('mydate', '2013-05-25', PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind the date as a string
$stmt->execute(); //run it
$result = $stmt->fetch(); //get the results
```

As far as my understanding goes the statement that results from the above would look like this as binding a string results in it being surrounded by quotes:

```
SELECT transactions.amount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.date = #'2013-05-25'#;
```

This causes an error and prevents the statement from running.

What's the best way to bind a date string in PDO without causing this error? I'm currently resorting to `sprintf`-ing the string which I'm sure is bad practise.

Edit: if I pass the hash-surrounded date then I still get the error as below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification:
>   -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (SQLExecute[-3030] at
>   ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ips\php\classes.php:49 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ips\php\classes.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ips\php\classes.php(52): database->execute() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ips\try2.php(12): database->resultset() #3 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ips\php\classes.php on line 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when using a prepared statement or a parameterized query you don't need to worry about delimiting string and date values; all of that is handled for you "behind the scenes".

I just tried the following and it worked for me:

```
<?php
$connStr = 
        'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Gord\\Desktop\\Database1.accdb;' .
        'Uid=Admin;Pwd=;';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);

$sql = 
        "INSERT INTO tblDateTest (dateCol) VALUES (?)";

$newDateTimeValue = "2013-06-30 17:18:19";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($sth->execute(array($newDateTimeValue))) {
    echo "Done\r\n";
}
else {
    $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: Duh, yes I just needed to remove all quotes and hashes and it now works. I feel kinda stupid for having to ask this now... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put your date (entire value) in the `bindValue` method. Example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT transactions.amount FROM transactions WHERE transactions.date = :mydate'); //prepare the query
$stmt->bindValue('mydate', '#2013-05-25#', PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind the date as a string
```

Comment: OK but won't that result in something like `...WHERE date='#2013-05-25#';`? I shall try all the same.

Comment: Yes - but see if it works first. If not, you may need to resort to running a raw query as you cannot remove quotes from a prepared statement like that.

Comment: it didn't work. see my above edit. @GordThompson solved it though

Comment: I had a hunch that PDO would have handled this without you having to provide the date delimiters. Good to know and confirm though. Thanks!